# Random effects in GAM and one other smooth make covariance matrix non-positive definite

Tags: r, regression, gam, mgcv

I am using `gam` in `mgcv` to fit the model

```
m <- gam(y ~ s(x) + s(Group, bs = "re"))
```

however this makes the covariance-matrix

```
vcov(m)
```

non-positive definite. Further, the estimated `s(x)` is just a straight line.

Now, removing the `s(x)` part fixes the `vcov` problem, and removing the `s(Group)` also fixes these problems and then the estimated curve `s(x)` is not a straight line.

Does anybody know why this happens, and how to fix it? Such that I can include both `s(x)` and `s(Group)`, and also get a positive-definite `vcov` matrix, and properly estimated curves (even if they were to be insignificant)?

I believe it is probably caused by the fact that `x` and `Group` are confounded to a degree, such that only one of them is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the penalized least squares problem is not full-rank, even after regularization by the ordinary quadratic penalty. Check your coefficients first. If any coefficients are exactly 0, then they are not identifiable and constrained at 0.

```
any(coef(m) == 0)
```

Note that unlike in `lm` and `glm`, where unidentifiable coefficients are coded `NA`, `mgcv` just uses 0. Of course, the resulting standard error of these coefficients are also 0, this is why the covariance matrix given by  `vcov` is not positive definite.

The fix is to use a stronger regularization. Try **shrinkage smooth** here, for example,

```
s(x, bs = 'cs', k = 10)
s(x, bs = 'ts', k = 10)
```

See `?smooth.terms` for all smoothing basis classes, including the shrinkage class.

---

Another thing to try is to make your model less flexible, by reducing the rank of `s(x)`, for example

```
s(x, k = 5)
s(x, k = 3)
```

The minimal `k` is 3 for cubic spline.

But this is not guaranteed to fix your problem, as if it is the NULL space of the `s(x)` that is confounded with `s(Group, bs = 're')`, you have to use shrinkage smooth to penalize the NULL space.